# Does the UAE law set the method of capital punishment for a given crime?

Tags: capital-punishment, uae

[The judicial system of UAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judicial_system_in_the_United_Arab_Emirates) allows a court (a *Federal court*, I believe) to pass judgment of the [capital punishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_in_the_United_Arab_Emirates) for crimes including homosexuality and denouncing Islam. The executions are carried through either a firing squad, hanging, or stoning. My question is, is the method of death sentence specified for each of the punishable crimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no statutory provision in the [Penal Code](https://www.adjd.gov.ae/sites/Authoring/AR/ELibrary%20Books/E-Library/PDFs/Penal%20Code.pdf) saying how the deal penalty is to be imposed. There is little by say of specification of the method in Sharia, except that stoning for adultery is mentioned in the Hadith (Sahih Muslim Book 17 [Hadith 4194](https://muflihun.com/muslim/17/4194), [4191](https://muflihun.com/muslim/17/4191)).